# ThreeJS Render 3D models without exposing the raw file in browser

Tags: browser, three.js, webgl

I have a project that i need to display bunch of 3d Models (OBJ, FBX, GLB) that are going to be presented in the browser, but when i use fileLoader i can see the HTTP request and it returns the raw file through the network.

I want to know if there's anyway i can display my models in browser without exposing them to clients ? (Due to copyright issues).

Comment: There is no way to do this. If you're publishing your models on the web, you're making them publicly available. See here for a list of discussions on this topic: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/protecting-code-and-objects-from-unauthorized-copying/24154

Comment: Thank you @Marquizzo for your answer, i guess that's something to keep in mind. but i came across a this website SketchFab and they have live 3d viewer which i'm not sure if it is ThreeJS or other libraries, but i noticed that the models are coming in as a zipped binary, is my assumption correct if i say they use their own algorithm to modify models and return as a zipped binary ?

Comment: It's probably just [GLTF Binary format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlTF#GLB). There are many 3D editors that can read this filetype.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316988424_SECURING_ONLINE_3D_WEB-BASED_MODELS_Research_in_Progress and https://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/protecting/article-html/ might be interesting reading.